# Software implementation of symmetric and asymmetric bilinear pairings

Tags: elliptic-curves, implementation, pairings

I have recently read a [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/354.pdf) about pairings, which only implemented asymmetric bilinear pairings and it mentiond that $\eta_{T}$ pairing is the most efficient algorithm for symmetric pairings. I wonder is there any software implementation on elliptic curves could achieve both asymmetric and symmetrci pairings e.g. $e(g,g), e(g,h), g\in G_{1}, h\in G_{2}$

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to [MAGMA](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/). To evaluate MAGMA scripts, in their website go to the tab *Calculator*. [Craige Costello](https://www.craigcostello.com.au/) has a free tutorial titled [Pairings for Beginners](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5fdbb09f31d71c1227082339/t/5ff394720493bd28278889c6/1609798774687/PairingsForBeginners.pdf) with examples of the Weil and Tate pairings in MAGMA.

Comment: I have found a solution for my project, but I am still grateful for your material. It's good for me to learn more about pairings under ECC.